# Dependency injection in my singleton class .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, singleton

I'm having trouble injecting the dependency I pass into the constructor of my Asegurador class.

When I want to instantiate, _instance = new Asegurador(); I don't have the parameter required by the constructor (IGeneralRepository), how can I solve this problem?

Note that my Asegurador class is a singleton.

```
private Asegurador(IGeneralRepository generalRepository)
    {
        _token = GetTokenAsync().Result;
        _repository = generalRepository;
    }
    public static Asegurador Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _local = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SEGUROS_LOCAL") ?? "local";
                _instance = new Asegurador();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The whole point of dependency injection is that you would never write `new Asegurador(...)`, you ask the container to give you an instance of `Asegurador` and it works out how to do it for you.

Comment: The point of singleton is that getting the same instance anytime you want to use it. Registering the class as singleton in your DI container does the same thing, but without having to keep a static field to ensure its lifetime spans the entire run.

Comment: Dependency Injection is a practice applied to Volatile Dependencies. Because of its behavior and dependencies, your `Asegurador` is a [Volatile Dependency](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/137), so you are correct in trying to apply DI here. [The Singleton pattern should only be used either from within the Composition Root or when the Dependency is Stable.](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-5/220)

Comment: The answers were not entirely clear to me, what I want is to inject the IGeneralRepository generalRepository dependency into my Asegurador class.

The problem is when I want to make new Asegurador() class, since I don't have a generalRepository object at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

When using a DI container you can (and should) let it take care of handling the **Lifetime** of a dependency.

.Net core's dependency injection lets you define 3 different lifetimes for your services ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)):

- *Transient*: a transient service is recreated each time it is injected
- *Scoped*: a scoped service is created once for each request
- *Singleton*: a singleton is created once in the whole application lifetime.

The best approach to achieve what you are trying to do is the following:

- Amend your Asegurador class so that it has a public constructor and get rid of the static *Instance* property

  ```
  public class Asegurador {
      public Asegurador(IGeneralRepository generalRepository)
      {
         _token = GetTokenAsync().Result; //I know too few about it but I would try to pass it as a dependency as well
         _repository = generalRepository;
      }
  }
  ```
- instead of calling *Asegurador.Instance* inject the dependency in the client class

  ```
   public class IUseTheAsegurador {
       private Asegurador _asegurador;
       public IUseTheAsegurador(Asegurador asegurador)
       {
         _asegurador = asegurador;
       }
   }
  ```
- Register all in the DI in your Startup.cs:

  ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      ...
      services.AddSingleton<Asegurador>();
      services.AddScoped<IUseAsegurador>(); //This can be Singleton or Transient as well, depending on your needs
      ...
   }
  ```

I (a lot of people actually :D) prefer this approach because it leaves the responsability of guaranteeing a single instance to the DI and also because lets you write unit tests for the client class (IUseTheAsegurador in the example) in an easier way.

Comment: What if I need to create some entity using its transient AppService, but I need to do it from Singleton class?